# Проверка выполнения операции

Tags: python, строки

Вопрос следующего характера:

Есть строка, в ней символы разделены некоторым количеством пробелов. Надо привести её к строке, в которой символы разделены лишь 1 пробелом.
Моё решение следующее:

```
b = "  " 
i = 1
while i > 0:
    str = str.replace(b, " ")
```

Присваиваю `b` значение 2 пробела, и заменяем во всей строке 2 пробела на 1. Таким образом, в строке между каждым символом в итоге останется 1 пробел.

Но, при моем подходе, надо проверить, произошла ли на очередной итерации цикла замена, что бы присвоить `i` значение `-1` и остановить цикл, если замены не произошло, и между каждым символом строки уже стоит 1 пробел. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать (если это можно сделать), если нельзя, то предложите своё решение.

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Не используйте имя `str` для вашей строки, потому что это имя встроенной функции.)

Вы пишете:

> ... надо проверить, произошла ли на очередной итерации цикла замена ...

Так эту проверку просто сделайте:

```
old_str = "Какая  красивая     девушка! "
new_str = ""
b = "  "

while new_str != old_str:
    new_str = old_str.replace(b, " ")
    new_str, old_str = old_str, new_str

print(new_str)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Какая красивая девушка!
> ```

Но ваш подход (заменять в цикле 2 пробели одним) не решит проблему с пробелями в начале (и в конце) строки — тогда один пробел остается.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

1. `_str` - строка
2. `_str.split()` - разбиение строки по разделителю пробел
3. `' '.join(список)` - сборка строки из списка с разделителем `' '`

---

```
_str = """

Вопрос следующего характера: 

Есть строка, в ней символы разделены некоторым количеством пробелов. 
Надо привести её к строке, в которой символы разделены лишь 1  пробелом.
"""

print(' '.join(_str.split()))
```

читаем Функции и методы строк https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html